# Moodle automatically update courses and categories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle11g, moodle

I'm developing an application (Java, Spring, Hibernate, OracleDB) who take courses and student information from one external DB and create the course with its resources on a Moodle 3.0.5+ (Build: 20160811) instance.

The application create successfully the Categories/sub-categories/Courses but it won't show up immediately. I have to go to /Site Administration/Courses/Manage Courses and Categories/ and trigger the "update" by selecting categories miscellaneous, press edit and the save, and voilà categories are showing up.

I need help to know how to trigger that update programmatically, any clue would be really appreciated.

Here is where i have to trigger manually the category update:
**[image: Here is where i have to trigger manually the category update]**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @martin-greenaway i've checked updated tables on update/create categories:

it's **mdl_logstore_log**, which have an column named 'eventname' with record

> \core\event\course_category_updated

So i'm guessing there isn't a trigger in the database but in moodle itself.

Comment: I can't do this for you obviously, as I don't have access to your program, but I think the best way to check what's going on would be to run your program, do a backup of the MySQL database to file.  Then do the Category -> Miscellaneous -> Edit -> Save trick, and do another backup of the MySQL database.  If you diff the two files, you should find the entry (or entries) in the database that you'll need to add.  e.g.

`mysqldump -h my-host-name --user=my-user-name --password=my-password "moodle-db-schema-name"`

Comment: Assuming that your Moodle database is running on MySQL, that is ... if it's oracle as well, then there are no doubt other tools which would do an export, or allow you to do a diff of two snapshots.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it helped. But there are mainly logs. I'm thinking now maybe that trigger is on Moodle itself.

Comment: Or, it could be horrible enough that it's a trigger based on that log table entry - but I'd hope that's not the case :)

Comment: I'll keep you informed, tomorrow i have to address this.

Comment: You'll find more on the internal Moodle Events API here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2